# How would I run an ANOVA in R on this long form data?

Tags: r, anova

My factors are constraint (high or low), picture type type (a,b,c,d), and electrode (29 values).

My dependent variable is the amplitude measured from the electrodes. So it is 2 x 4 x 29. How can I run the ANOVA so that R does not think that each of the electrodes is another measurement but included in the 'electrode' factor?

This is what I tried so far but I get an error

```
anova1 <- ezANOVA(data=dat, dv=n_400, wid=subject, within=.(constraint, ending, electrode), type="III")


>Error in ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within = within,  : 
  One or more cells is missing data. Try using ezDesign() to check your data.
```